# Create network namespace with full network access [LINUX]

Tags: linux, networking, dns, openvpn, namespace

I created a linux namespace using this script :

```
read -p "ip : " ip

ip netns add myvpn

ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
ip netns exec myvpn ip link set lo up

ip link add vpn0 type veth peer name vpn1
ip link set vpn0 up
ip link set vpn1 netns myvpn up
ip addr add $ip/24 dev vpn0
ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add $ip/24 dev vpn1
ip netns exec myvpn ip route add default via $ip dev vpn1

iptables -A INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s $ip/24 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $ip/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

mkdir -p /etc/netns/myvpn
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf
```

However it seems that I don't have a full network access in the namespace :

```
ip netns exec myvpn ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Actually, idrk what "Temporary failure in name resolution" means...

Any idea to make this work ?

Comment: 1) Start an `xterm` in your network namespace, that makes debugging easier. 2) Try `ping 8.8.8.8` to see if the network connection itself works. 3) Make sure `ens3` is really the network interface that connects your main namespace to the internet.

Comment: Network connection doesn't seems to work: when running "ping 8.8.8.8", I get : From "ip" icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: Try `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ip route get 8.8.8.8` from the main name space. Also, you've given both `vpn0` and `vpn1` the address `$ip` (which one did you choose?). I don't think that works.

Comment: I can see 3 misconceptions: 1/ assign your router an IP address and your routed system the same IP 2/ ask that system to use as default gateway its own IP address (it will just be turned into "do ARP requests for any IP address" as if there was no such gateway) 3/ ask your router to route a foreign IP that already belongs to it locally. (yes, router and routed system is what it's about when using network namespaces)

Comment: as a more real life illustration: if your standard home router had the address 192.168.1.1/24, would you expect this to work if your computer were also using 192.168.1.1/24 and have a default gateway of ... 192.168.1.1? Could you ping 8.8.8.8 from it?

Comment: "Temporary failure in name resolution" means typically that your system is unable to reach any of the listed nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and as such is unable to translate names (not found in `/etc/hosts` or equivalent) to IP addresses for network operations.